# NewCookie.getMaxAge() always returns -1

Tags: java, rest, cookies, jersey-client

I have two servers. S1 and S2. S2 is a REST API based server. S1 is an HttpServlet. I get a request to S1from client browser. I retrieve the request URI and Request method and based on certain conditions make call to a particular REST API on S2. For making these calls I am using jersey client (ver -1.17).
Now, when I response from S2, I extract a cookie from the response, i.e cookie-domain, maxAge, path etc.This is required because I need to create a new cookie out of that and add it to the final response that S1 is going to send back to the client. (I couldn't find any other way to just pass on the cookies on response from S1). But when I retrieve maxAge as -

cookieMaxAge = cookie.getMaxAge();   // This cookie is an object of   javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie

It returns -1. So when I try to add new cookie to the final response, it is not being created on the browser.

Is it a bug in jersey client or anything I am doing wrong? I tried to search answers for this but no lucl. I am new to web programming and REST APIs. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A tad late, but -1 is used for making a cookie session based. This means the cookie expires as soon as you close your browser session.